# How to create LinkExtractor rule which based on href in Scrapy

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to create simple crawler with `Scrapy` (scrapy.org). As per example `item.php` is allowed. How I can write rule which allow url which always start with `http://example.com/category/` but in `GET` parameter `page` should be there with any number of digit with other parameter. Order of these parameter is random.
   Please help How I can write such a rule?

Few valid values are:

- http://example.com/category/?page=1&sort=a-z&cache=1
- http://example.com/category/?page=1&sort=a-z#
- http://example.com/category/?sort=a-z&page=1

Following is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'example.com'
allowed_domains = ['example.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/category/']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item'),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = scrapy.Item()
    item['id'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_id"]/text()').re(r'ID: (\d+)')
    item['name'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_name"]/text()').extract()
    item['description'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_description"]/text()').extract()
    return item
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test for `http://example.com/category/` at the start of the string and the `page` parameter with one or more digits in the value:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('^http://example.com/category/\?.*?(?=page=\d+)', )), callback='parse_item'),
```

Demo (using your example urls):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^http://example.com/category/\?.*?(?=page=\d+)')
>>> should_match = [
...     'http://example.com/category/?sort=a-z&page=1',
...     'http://example.com/category/?page=1&sort=a-z&cache=1',
...     'http://example.com/category/?page=1&sort=a-z#'
... ]
>>> for url in should_match:
...     print "Matches" if pattern.search(url) else "Doesn't match"
... 
Matches
Matches
Matches
```

Answer (score -2):

**try like this**

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'<[^>]+href="((http:\/\/example.com\/category\/)([^"]+))"', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"<a class=\"youarehere\" href=\"http://example.com/category/?sort=newest\">newest</a>\n \n<a href=\"http://example.com/category/?sot=frequent\">frequent</a>"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

[**live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fD0mB3/1)